# Saving twitter stream not properly saved in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, twitter, stream

So I wanted to save the stream of data from Twitter Streaming API in MongoDB using Mongoose. Somehow it doesn't save all of the data and it only saves 1 document out of the infinite amount of data in the stream(that is not complete) when i run my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
TwitterStream = require('twitter-stream-api'),
fs = require('fs');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/insert_sample');

var keys = {
consumer_key : "",
consumer_secret : "",
token : "",
token_secret : ""
};

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var userSchema = new Schema({}, {"strict": false});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = User;

var Twitter = new TwitterStream(keys, false);
Twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {
track: 'travel'
});

// create a new user called twitter
var Twitter = new User();

// call the built-in save method to save to the database
Twitter.save(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;

console.log('User saved successfully!');
});
```

Output of the command line: `User saved successfully!`

When I try to query in MongoDB shell using `db.users.find()`, the result is this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a60a5558f4f1d21bcadd72b"), "__v" : 0 }
```

When it should be like:

```
{
"created_at": "Fri Aug 04 05:42:03 +0000 2017",
"id": 893346273255866400,
"id_str": "893346273255866368",
..........and soooo many more attributes }
```

EDIT!!! Sorry I accidentally hit enter and posted it without the other needed things to be clear. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your Twitter Variable and saving the user data empty object.

```
// create a new user called twitter
var Twitter = new User();

// call the built-in save method to save to the database
Twitter.save(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
```

Once you create a stream you need to *listen for data event* and use that data to save in your database.

Remove above lines and use something like;

```
 // listen for data from stream
    Twitter.on('data', function (obj) {

        var data =  obj.toString('utf8');
        console.log(data);
        var TwitterData = new User(data); // create object 
        TwitterData.save(); // save data to DB

    });
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for responding! I did what you instructed but it stores yet another thing, and not the stream from twitter streaming api. Heres the output `data <Buffer 7b 22 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 5f 61 74 22 3a 22 54 68 75 20 4a 61 6e 20 31 38 20 31 34 3a 35 34 3a 31 36 20 2b 30 30 30 30 20 32 30 31 38 22 2c 22 69 64 ... >` @H. Mahinda

Comment: convert buffer to string like: obj.toString('utf8');

Comment: I inserted it before `console.log('data', obj);` still no changes :( @H. Mahinda

Comment: Also, is writing `var userSchema = new Schema({}, {"strict": false});` correct if the data that im streaming does not always have consistent attributes? Because some tweets contain coordinates while others dont. Same with picture URLs.